# angularjs bootstrap typeahead return child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

My input binds to object `line.product` however `typeahead` is returning the list of pairs of products and supplier. The current `ps.product as ps.product.code for ps in getProductSupplierRefList($viewValue)`  does not return the expected `product`.

[image]

```
<input ng-model="line.product"
                               class=" form-control"
                               typeahead="ps.product as ps.product.code for ps in getProductSupplierRefList($viewValue)"
                               typeahead-loading="isLoading"
                               typeahead-on-select="productSupplierSelected($item, line)"
                               typeahead-template-url="productSupplierRefList.html"/>
```

`getProductSupplierRefList` calls webapi and return a list of `ProductSupplierRefModel`:

```
public class ProductSupplierRefModel
{

    public ProductRefModel Product { get; set; }

    public SupplierRefModel Supplier { get; set; }

}
```

The product code is expected in text control:
[image]

Any suggestion pls?

Comment: where is getProductSupplierRefList function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `typeahead-input-formatter` to show the code. looks like `ps.product as ps.product.code` is not working???

```
<input ng-model="line.product"
                               type="text"
                               class=" form-control"
                               ng-keyup="getProductSupplierRefList($event)"
                               typeahead="ps.product as ps.product.code for ps in filterProductSuppliers"
                               typeahead-loading="isLoading"
                               typeahead-input-formatter="formatProduct($model)"
                               typeahead-wait-ms=500
                               typeahead-on-select="productSupplierSelected($item, line)"
                               typeahead-template-url="productSupplierRefList.html" />
```

where the formatter is:

```
$scope.formatProduct=function(model) {
        return model ? model.code : '';
    }
```

the product code now appears as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use function in typehead. Also be careful about the model properties camel case.

```
<input ng-model="line.product"
                           class=" form-control"
                           ng-keyup="getProductSupplierRefList($event)"
                           typeahead="ps.Product as ps.Product.Code for ps in productOptions"
                           typeahead-loading="isLoading"
                           typeahead-on-select="productSupplierSelected($item, line)"
                           typeahead-template-url="productSupplierRefList.html"/>



 $scope.productOptions = [];
$scope.getProductSupplierRefList = function(evt){
       var value = angular.element(evt.target).val();
       $http.get('url/' + value).then(funtion(response){
             $scope.productOptions = response.data;
        })
}
//test ps.Product.Code with _tojson(ps.Product.Code)
$scope._tojson= function(obj){
       return angular.toJson(obj);
}
```

Comment: Also be careful about the model properties camel case.

Comment: add $viewValue=undefined with ng-change?

Comment: Sorry, use line.product instead of $viewValue

Comment: line.product is object product when the $viewValue is partial text for filtering the productSupplier list

Comment: OK! I updated. Use event and ng-keyup instead of model.

Comment: I addes a fake _tojson. fn. can you test _tojson(ps.product.code) on typehead attribute to see what is the object.

Comment: it returns string

Comment: it works with `typeahead-input-formatter`. any idea?

Comment: It is OK, if work. Maybe it is a bug. Beacuse in bootstrap-typehead-documents they say typehead directive is equivalent of ng-options.